# How to compare and change values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

My table looks like:

```
[Number]     [Value1]
1234567         8
1234567C        7
9876543         1
9876543C        2
5555555         3
5555555C        3
```

I want to search the entries for same values in the first column (except the "C" in the end of the number) and set the higher value in the second column to the lower one.
There are always only two same values (one with "C") and some pairs have same values in the second column and some have different.

The result of the query should be:

```
Number          Value1
1234567           7
1234567C          7
9876543           1
9876543C          1
5555555           3
5555555C          3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Simply saying you have to make an `UPDATE` statement, selecting corresponding rows (number and numberC), compare values and if one is bigger, check if it's the one without C, if it is - decrease the number. Simples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is not an ideal solution but should do what you want:

```
update yourTable
set value1 = (
select min(value1) from (
select * from yourTable
) as x
where yourTable.number = x.number + 'C');
```

I have tested it with this in mysql workbench:

```
create table yourTable(number varchar (10),value1 int);
insert into yourTable Values('1234567',8);
insert into yourTable Values('1234567C',7);
insert into yourTable Values('9876543',1);
insert into yourTable Values('9876543C',2);
insert into yourTable Values('5555555',3);
insert into yourTable Values('5555555C',3);
insert into yourTable Values('55555556',10);
insert into yourTable Values('55555556C',2);
```

Then `select * from yourTable;`will return:

```
1234567     8
1234567C    7
9876543     1
9876543C    2
5555555     3
5555555C    3
55555556    10
55555556C   2
```

After the update `select * from yourTable;` will return:

```
1234567     7
1234567C    7
9876543     1
9876543C    1
5555555     3
5555555C    3
55555556    2
55555556C   2
```

Hope that is what you wanted :)

Comment: Hi! This works great, it is easy enough for a MySQL Dummy to understand :-)Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need any checking, since there are only 2 values (and thus the query is even simpler):

```
UPDATE 
    table
SET
    Value1 = 
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(Value1)
        FROM
            table t
        WHERE
            table.Number = t.Number 
            OR table.Number = t.Number + 'C' 
    )
WHERE
    RIGHT(Number, 1) != 'C'
```